# ¿Por qué se anteponen números extraños cuando intento imprimir el binario?

Tags: c

Existe un problema en la impresión del contenido del puntero que no se como solucionar. Antes de imprimir el numero binario se anteponen números que no sé de dónde salen, y el compilador me indica de que binario no tiene referencia.

```c
void fBinaria(int numero) {
  
    int binario[A], * pa,i=0;
    pa = binario;
    
    while (numero > 0) {
        
        *pa = numero % 2;
        numero /= 2;
       
        pa++;
        i++;

    }

   
    for (int j = i; j >=0 ; j--) {
       
        
        printf("%d", *pa);
       
        pa--;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @MrDave1999 la idea es imprimir `binario` hacia atrás.

Comment: por favor publica un [mcve], incluidos los mensajes del compilador sin editar.

Comment: lo siento es mi primera vez publicando este tipo de cosas y no sabia como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

> > ¿Por qué se anteponen números extraños cuando intento imprimir el binario?

El problema radica que el bucle `while` genera una iteración adicional, esto provoca que las variables `i` y `pa` se incrementen. Así que `pa` terminaría apuntando a una dirección de memoria donde su contenido es basura.

Por ejemplo, si el parámetro `numero` recibiera el número `11`, la variable `i` terminaría en la posición `4` y `pa` apuntaría al dato que esté en el índice `4`, el problema que ese dato es *basura*.

**Solución:** Se debe cambiar la condición de salida del bucle `while`, así que dejará de iterar hasta que `numero` sea `1`:

```c
void fBinaria(int numero) 
{
    int binario[A], *pa, i=0;
    pa = binario;
    
    while (numero != 1)
    {
        *pa = numero % 2;
        numero /= 2;
        pa++;
        i++;

    }
    *pa = 1;
    
    for (int j = i; j >=0 ; j--) 
    {
        printf("%d", *pa);
        pa--;
    }
}
```